# update object properties from inside function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the values in `validations` inside of the function it sets `isValid to false` however it doesn't update `validations` outside of the function, how can i do this?

```
export let validations = {
    validate: null,
    isValid: true,
    validationMessage: ''
};

function validateInput(value) {
    if (value == null || value.length === 0) {
        const update = {...validations, isValid: false}
        {console.log(bla)}
    return update
}
```

Comment: Why create a new object instead of `validations.isValid = false` ?

Comment: I would like to avoid mutating the object

Comment: Then your question makes no sense _"I'm trying to update the values in validations ... however it doesn't update validations outside of the function"_.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
export let validations = {
    validate: null,
    isValid: true,
    validationMessage: ''
};

function validateInput(value) {
    if (value == null || value.length === 0) {
      validations.isValid = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but, the way you constructed your code I think it is inevitable. You are exporting it and consuming it somewhere else, so you cannot expect your function to return not mutated object and to change object's value in place where you are using it. I suggest restructuring your code, which would be completely different question and issue. If my answer was correct and it works, could you mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want the actual validations object to be intact and your validateInput function should return it's validation result

```
export let validations = {
    validate: null,
    isValid: true,
    validationMessage: ''
};

function validateInput(value) {
    const update = {...validations};
    if (value == null || value.length === 0) {
        update.isValid = false;
    }
    return update;
}
```

or something like

```
export let validations = {
    validate: function(value){
     if (value == null || value.length === 0) {
        this.isValid = false;
        this.validationMessage = 'No value'
    }},
    reset: function(){
        this.isValid = true;
        this.validationMessage = '';
    },
    isValid: true,
    validationMessage: ''
};
```